# Does 866 cM shared suggest half aunt rather than aunt?

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, relationship-analysis

There is a joke in my family that my father's father is not his biological father. He only has sisters and his father is dead, so there's no possibility of a true test. But I'm his daughter and I did a DNA test, and here's what I got.

I got DNA results back and here's what it says about one of my aunts that tested too. Great aunt or cousin is the link they gave us.

```
12,2% (866,2‎ cM)
DNA shared
19
Segments shared
106,2‎ cM
Segment longest
```

Does that actually mean the joke is true and my aunt is my half aunt?

Answer (score -1):

From [The Shared cM Project 3.0 tool v4 for 866 cM](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/866) the possible relationships do not include aunt.

However, they do include half aunt.

Comment: yes I did use that, so it tends to confirm my aunt is my "half aunt"